# overwrite redirect_to in action_controller/metal/redirecting.rb

Tags: ruby-on-rails

i need to modify default redirect_to method in actionpack/lib/action_controller/metal/redirecting.rb

```
def redirect_to(options = {}, response_status = {}) #:doc:
      ....
      self.location      = _compute_redirect_to_location(options)
      # add customized code here to modify self.location
      ......
end
```

i am not sure what is the correct approach.  what i did are the followings:

- copy redirecting.rb to my rails project in
  "lib/rails_ext/action_controller/redirecting.rb"
- made the change to redirect_to() method
- add the line: require 'rails_ext/action_controller/redirecting' in application.rb

it worked. however, i am getting an warning
rails_ext/action_controller/redirecting.rb:3: warning: already initialized constant DEFAULT_MESSAGE

in additional, i think there must be a better way to accomplish this.

Comment: Instead of overwriting it, you could re-implement your own version and just call that instead. Out of curiousity, what is it you're trying to change?

Comment: i am using some open source code, internally they call redirect_to numerous times. i have web server and rails server running on 2 different hosts. web server takes the https requests, then redirect to my rails server via http.  but when rails server redirects, i want it to redirect using https instead of http.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I usually override this function in application controller.

```
def redirect_to(*args)
 # your code
end
```

similar article: http://jkfill.com/2011/05/13/log-which-line-called-redirect_to/

Answer (score 0):

The right method in Ruby is to redefine the function. You can see an example [here](http://ruby.about.com/od/rubyfeatures/a/aliasing.htm) (chapter "Change the Behavior of a Class").